# Append suffix to a pandas series index

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

Given the following Panda series:

```
>>>series = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=["a", "b", "c"])
>>>series
a   1
b   2
c   3
dtype: int64
```

Is there a way to produce this?

```
>>>series.do_something()
a_x   1
b_x   2
c_x   3
dtype: int64
```

### Background

I have a Series that was produced from a DataFrame aggregate function: `df.sum()`

The indexes are currently the column names, but I want them to be the column names plus `_sum`, like so:

```
>>>data
col1_sum   500.00
col2_sum   9324.0
col3_sum   0.2340
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
In [49]: series.index += '_sum'

In [50]: series
Out[50]:
a_sum    1
b_sum    2
c_sum    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe `series.add_suffix('_x')` matches what you need!

And `series.add_prefix('x_')` returns something like this:

```
x_a    1
x_b    2
x_c    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you can use `str.replace`.

```
s.index = s.index.str.replace('(.*)', r'\1_sum') 

print(s)
a_sum    1
b_sum    2
c_sum    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is curious about using this for a DataFrame, the snippet below accomplishes the task.

Where df is a pandas DataFrame and 'C_' is the desired prefix.

The default behavior of add_prefix for a DataFrame is to add the prefix to the columns. Thus the transpose and then add_prefix and then transpose back.

df = df.T.add_prefix('C_').T